# How can I implement a timeout mechanism for a suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-sharedflow

I'm trying to implement a timeout mechanism on a suspend function which returns a `SharedFlow`.  I was launching a coroutine using `CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch { }`  but I've [read](https://elizarov.medium.com/coroutine-context-and-scope-c8b255d59055) that it's not a good practice. It's suggested to make function a `CoroutineScope` extension instead. But it's necessary for me to make that function suspend. How can I implement a timeout mechanism for a suspend function which needs to return the flow?

Here is a simplified version of my implementation:

```kotlin
class Client {
    sealed interface State {
        object Loading: State
        data class Success(val message: String): State
        object Error: State
    }

    interface MyCallListener {
        suspend fun onResult(result: State)
    }

    val methodListeners: MutableMap<String, MyCallListener> = mutableMapOf()

    suspend inline fun call(): SharedFlow<State> {
        val id = randomUUID()
        val flow = MutableSharedFlow<State>()

        //onResult is called elsewhere. this way, it's possible to emit a result to the flow
        methodListeners[id] = object : MyCallListener {
            override suspend fun onResult(result: State) {
                flow.emit(result)
            }
        }

        flow.tryEmit(State.Loading)

        send(methodMessage) //this is a suspend function which uses a suspend function of ktors websocket session

        CoroutineScope(coroutineContext).launch {
            var latestValue: State? = null
            launch {
                flow.collect {
                    latestValue = it
                }
            }
            delay(5000)
            if (latestValue is State.Loading) {
                flow.emit(State.Error)
            }
        }

        return flow
    }

    fun onReceiveMessage(id: String, message: String) {
        methodListeners[id]?.onResult(State.Success(message))
    }

}
```

I need to call that function from another suspend function:

```kotlin
class MyUseCase(
    val client: Client
) {
    suspend fun foo() = client.call()
}
```

This currently works but since it's not recommended to use CoroutineScope(coroutineContext) and I can't make it a CoroutineScope extension, is there a better way to do this?

Edit: Here is more context on what I'm trying to accomplish. The client is a WebSocket message handler. I'm sending WebSocket messages called "method" with an id, and keep a listener instance with that id. When a result message is received with the same id, I get the listener instance with it and call listener.onResult. I implemented this call function so I can receive the method result with a flow. But sometimes, the server never sends a result message with that id. So the state is stuck as loading state. I wanted to implement a timeout mechanism for that matter.

Comment: Did you try [`withTimeout`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-timeout.html)?

Comment: Won't withTimeout suspend the function? I want it to return the flow immediately.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it will suspend the function". `withTimeout` is a suspend function that wraps a timeout around a suspend function, which is what you are looking for as far as I can tell from the question. It won't add any delays.

Comment: There are a number of oddities with this code so it’s hard to tell exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Rarely should you need a suspend function to generate a flow since a flow can suspend internally for its first emission. And especially with a SharedFlow. If it’s shared, presumably you’re going to cache it after calling this function, but since it suspends you have to cache it in a nullable or lateinit property, which makes it not useful for collecting from multiple places. Why can’t this function be an extension of CoroutineScope?

Comment: You shouldn’t be using CoroutineScope().launch unless you want that part of your functionality to be non-cancellable no matter if the original coroutine was cancelled. But IMO, GlobalScope should always be preferred in that situation to make it clear you *mean* for it to be global. The docs for GlobalScope say you shouldn’t replace it with CoroutineScope().

Comment: What do you want exactly? You want to call some function and if it doesn't return anything till 500ms return an error?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've added more detail to the question. @Tenfour04 this actually works with CoroutineScope().launch but I don't want to use it for the same reasons. I didn't want to make this an extension of CoroutineScope because it's an instance function of the Client. I will need to call it using with(client) { scope.call } everywhere and I think that's ugly. This is a suspend function because it uses a suspend function on the body (i've removed it before for the sample)

Comment: That helps a little, but I'm still quite confused about exactly what you're doing because there are so many bizarre details about the design you currently have--the signature of this function, why you'd generate a hot flow on each call to a function, why there's a listener that the class internally replaces on each call to the function, breaking previously returned flows, why you need a separate coroutine scope at all, etc. I think a better way to communicate what you're trying to do might be to explain why my answer below doesn't meet your exact needs.

Comment: I've added more from my actual implementation to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m guessing a little at what you’re trying to do. I think the SharedFlow should be a `val` property since it’s shared. You don’t want multiple calls to this function silently killing previous flows that it returned (which your code does by replacing the listener each time). And then the listener should not be publicly changeable either.

```
private val backingCallStateFlow = MutableSharedFlow<State>(replay = 1)
    .apply { tryEmit(State.Loading) }

// use this to emit new State instead of the listener
fun updateCallState(state: State) {
    backingCallStateFlow.tryEmit(state)
}
    
val callStateFlow = methodListenerFlow.transformLatest {
    emit(it)
    delay(5000L)
    emit(State.Error)
}
// you can tag this with shareIn if appropriate
```

The behavior here is that when you start collecting the flow, it emits states that were set with `updateState()`, and if one becomes stale (not updated within 5 seconds) it emits an error state.

Comment: I'm actually trying to mimic a HTTP request with using websockets. So every 'call' to an endpoint should have it's own flow: Loading -> Success/Error etc. And I need to collect from that flow on the call site, let's say on my ViewModel. So call function needs to return the flow. But idea of transforLatest looks promising. I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 0):

https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-timeout-or-null.html

Try to use the withTimeoutOrNull

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

    class Client {
        sealed interface State {
            object Loading: State
            object Success: State
            object Error: State
        }
    
        interface MyCallListener {
            suspend fun onResult(result: State)
        }
    
        var methodListener: MyCallListener? = null
    
        suspend fun call(): SharedFlow<State> {
            val flow = MutableSharedFlow<State>()
    
            // onResult is called elsewhere. This way, it's possible to emit a result to the flow
            methodListener = object : MyCallListener {
                override suspend fun onResult(result: State) {
                    flow.emit(result)
                }
            }
    
            flow.tryEmit(State.Loading)
    
            try {
                val latestValue = withTimeoutOrNull(5000) {
                    flow.firstOrNull { it != State.Loading }
                }
    
                if (latestValue == null) {
                    flow.emit(State.Error)
                }
            } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
                flow.emit(State.Error)
            }
    
            return flow
        }
    }
```

Comment: Won't withTimeout suspend the function? I want it to return the flow immediately.